# How do I use Wireshark to get websites visited?

Tags: http, wireshark

For example, if I visit https://www.google.com, how do I get it to show on Wireshark? I've tried filtering by HTTP, but when I visit the website I don't see anything on Wireshark.

I'm really inexperienced at Wireshark and these kinds of things in general, and I would appreciate it if you could help!

Comment: Wireshark will only see encrypted data when you visit a HTTPS site.  You could possibly get the domain using the `ssl.handshake.extensions_server_name` filter, but that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You said you were filtering via HTTP which is port 80 TCP, but the address you are visiting is HTTPS which is port 443 TCP.